# Update single column using more joins

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update one table column based on more join tables like below query,

```
update building 
set name = 'Payment' 
where id in (select id 
             from 
                 (select b.id 
                  from t1 d 
                  join t2 dl 
                  join t3 a 
                  join t4 f 
                  join t5 b on d.id = dl.id 
                            on a.id = dl.id 
                            on a.id = f.id  
                            on b.id = f.id 
                  where d.deviceId='002') as id);
```

I get an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on a.id=dl.areaId on a.floorId=f.id  on b.id=f.buildingId where d.deviceId='022'' at line 1

but when I change the query like below,

```
update building 
set name = 'Payment' 
where id in (select id from 
(select b.id from t1 d join t2 dl join t3 a join t4 f join t5 b where d.id=dl.id and a.id=dl.id 
and a.id=f.id  and b.id=f.id and d.deviceId='022') as id);
```

It works fine as what i expected. so where i am doing mistake in first one query?

I know that this subquery is not good for performance so please suggest me the good way to do this update.

Comment: In first query you have `b.id=f.id where d.deviceId='002'` and you are getting error as `where d.deviceId='F4B8' at line 1` are you sure the error is from the first given query ?

Comment: This is confusing use a clear syntax `UPDATE X JOIN Y ON... JOIN Z ON.. SET whatver` After each JOIN put the ON condition

Comment: Each `ON <condition>` must follow the corresponding `JOIN` because it is part of the `JOIN` syntax. Read the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). i.e. `...from t1 d join t2 dl on d.id=dl.id join t3 a on a.id=dl.id join t4 f ...` a.s.o.